# Hazelcast - Deleted Object returns to partition after few minutes

Tags: java, hazelcast

We have a multi node Hazelcast cluster. Data is spread across partitions. This data is related to certain information in Object.

What we are observing is that even after the Object is deleted from the partition it is coming back into the partitions again after sometime. After deletion the Object is not created

Have you ever faced a similar situation ?

Comment: what Object you mean, in EJB or in JSF or what exactly?

Comment: Data Object in HazelCast cluster. Example a simple map created in Hazelcast

Comment: Test in a simple standalone application, pretty sure it won't happen. Something has to put the object back into the map or for some other reason it is not actually deleted (maybe a typo in key creation when deleting). How do you make sure it is deleted? Is it unavailable right after deletion or is it just good faith that it actually was deleted at all?